# Received "Error loading partial Info.Plist template file when build Xamarin Forms iOS app

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using VS2019 on a PC, with a Mac linked to it for building iOS apps. When I build the app I receive the message:

> Error loading partial Info.plist template file
> 'obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mbt/Info.plist': Could not find a part of
> the path
> "/Users/myname/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/AppName.iOS/d86221a1e115ab3d2d619d810102d13413d6ff1743aadea6dda89b4af30fbe19/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mbt/Info.plist".

The only way I have found to prevent it is to go on the Mac, find the folder mentioned, and delete it. The I can build again for a while until it happens again.

Has anyone else had this problem?  If so, is there a fix?

Comment: Did you try to update Xcode and Visual studio to the latest and check if problem persists?

Comment: OSX, XCode, VSMac and VS 2019 all on the latest released version.

Comment: Sorry I can't be able to reproduce this problem, consider raising issue on github : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue and eventually figured out that deleting the bin\Debug\net8.0-ios and then rebuilding fixed it.